# Two inequalities with Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inequalities

How can I prove these two statements:
For any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \geq 2$ the inequality

$\left(|x|^{p-2}x-|y|^{p-2}y\right)(x-y) \geq 0$

holds and the second inequality

$\left(|x|^{p-2}x-|y|^{p-2}y\right) \leq C\left(|x|^{p-2}+|y|^{p-2}\right)|x-y|$

is valid?

Comment: How about the value of $p$? In the general case the first inequalyty is not true, as the result `{{x -> 99/5, y -> 12/5, p -> -(28/5)}}` of `FindInstance[(x - y)*(x^(p - 2)*x - y^(p - 2)*y) < 0 && x >= 0 && 
  y >= 0, {x, y, p}, Reals]`  demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality follows from the increase of the function defined by the expression `RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x`. That can be proved in Mathematica in such a way.

```
Factor[D[RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x, x]]
(*RealAbs[x]^(-4 + p) (-2 x^2 + p x^2 + RealAbs[x]^2)*)
```

Next,

```
Reduce[-2 x^2 + p x^2 + RealAbs[x]^2 >= 0, {x, p}, Reals]
(*(x < 0 && p >= 1) || x == 0 || (x > 0 && p >= 1)*)
```

Unfortunately, the `Reduce` command cannot crack the inequality `D[RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x, x]>=0` so one has to factor the LHS and to omit the first multiplier which is nonnegative.

The constant $C$ in the second inequality depends on $p$. Mathematica proves it for concrete values of $p$, e.g.

```
p = 7/2; NMaximize[(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x - RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)*y)/
RealAbs[x - y]/(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2) + RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)), {x, y}, 
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(*{1.25, {x -> -108.866, y -> -108.866}}*)
```

Let us put

```
ClearAll[x, y, p]; 
f[p_] := NMaximize[(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x - RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)*y)/
RealAbs[x - y]/(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2) + RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)), {x, y}, 
Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

Then

```
Plot[f[p][[1]], {p, 2, 9}]
```

[image]

Finally, the command

```
NMaximize[{(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x - RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)*y)/
RealAbs[x - y]/(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2) + RealAbs[y]^(p - 2))/(p - 1),  p >= 3}, {x, y, p}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(*{0.5, {x -> -24.9926, y -> -24.9952, p -> 3.}}*)
```

says that $p-1$ can be taken as $C(p)$ for $p\ge 3$.

Comment: At last, the result `{1., {x -> -17.9532, y -> -17.9793, p -> 3.}}` of `NMaximize[{(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2)*x - RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)*y)/
    RealAbs[x - y]/(RealAbs[x]^(p - 2) + RealAbs[y]^(p - 2)), 
  p >= 2 && p <= 3}, {x, y, p}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]` fills the gap.